# Как запретить удаление определенных записей?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В таблицу добавил `boolean` поле `deleting`. Записи, у которых `deleting` равно `false`, удалять нельзя.

Для реализации этого я добавил этот код в модель:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    before_destroy :can_i_delete_this?

    def can_i_delete_this?
        unless deleting
            errors[:base] << 'This item can not be deleted.'
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

Но при удалении элемента:

```
def destroy
    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    item.destroy
    redirect_to action: :index
end
```

Он без проблем удаляется. Где я свернул не там?

*P.S. У удаляемой записи поле `deleting` имеет значение `false`.*

Answer (score 2):

Судя по `ApplicationRecord`, это **Rails 5**. А там [обрыв цепочки коллбэков путём возврата `false` больше не работает](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17227).

Вместо `return false` теперь нужен `throw(:abort)`.